# How to convert from _bstr_t to System::String

Tags: c++-cli, string-conversion

Firstly, I'm some what new to *C++/CLI*.

After doing some research I've found that I can use `Marshal::PtrToStringBSTR` to convert an `IntPtr` to `System::String`. So, is there a way to convert my `_bstr_t` variable to an `IntPtr` so that I can pass it to the function mentioned and do conversion?

Or,

What is the correct way of converting a `_bstr_t` variable to `System::String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `marshal_as` to get a `System::String`.

```
marshal_as<System::String^>(value);
```

Here's the MSDN page for the different string types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Most important thing is to pay attention to the right #include depending on your string type.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as `marshal_as` function seems to convert `_bstr_t` without much cast and intermediate conversions. But Including a file is still a pain. I already have the namespace `System::Runtime::InteropServices` added and am using several functions from it, so I thought using `Marshal::PtrToStringBSTR` may be suitable for me for sake of uniformity. Kindly check the answer I posted and please tell me whether its a right way.

Answer (score 6):

System::String has a constructor that takes a wchar_t*.  Which makes this code work:

```
_bstr_t bs(L"Hello world");
String^ ss = gcnew String(bs.GetBSTR(), 0, bs.length());
```

Passing the length() ensures that embedded zeros are properly handled.  If you don't care about that then you can simply use gcnew String(bs.GetBSTR());

Comment: upvote! I tried this but didn't pass that length so, the compiler couldn't resolve which constructor to use! But yes, this works!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution through the way I mentioned itself, by using `Marshal::PtrToStringBSTR`. This is what I did:

```
void SomeFunction( String^% str )
{
    _bstr_t bs(L"Hello world");
    str = Marshal::PtrToStringBSTR(
          static_cast<IntPtr>( bs.GetAddress()));
}
```